# How to compare a user choice with a list of item and a list of boolean value?

Tags: python, list, boolean

I have this code, and i want to compare if the choice of a user (from the list "choix") is equal to the list "bonne_reponse".
the user see only the question and a choice of responce.

For exemple:
choix = [tomatos, apple, grappe, citrus]
bonne_reponse = [True, False, False, False]

"Question ?: In this list, What is not a fruit?

1 - tomatos
2 - apple
3 - grappe
4 - citrus

your responce (between 1 to 4) :

The good answer is 1, but i receive alway "wrong answer"(Mauvaise reponse) and is suppose for this one to be "Good answer"(Bonne reponse)

The data i use come like this:
{..."questions": [{"titre"`:"...?", "choix": [["tomatos", true], ["apple", false], ........]]}], ...}

There is the part of my code where the bug come:

```
    def FromData(data):
    # séparer la liste "choix" en 2 listes, une pour les choix et une pour les bonnes réponses
    choix = []
    bonne_reponse = []

    for i in range(len(data["choix"])):
        choix.append(data["choix"][i][0])
        bonne_reponse.append(data["choix"][i][1])
        # transformer la liste "bonne_reponse" en int pour pouvoir la comparer avec la réponse de l'utilisateur
        bonne_reponse[i] = int(bonne_reponse[i])

        # print(data["choix"])
        # print(choix)
        # print(bonne_reponse)
        # q = Question(data["titre"], data["choix"][i][0], data["choix"][i][1])
    q = Question(data["titre"], choix, bonne_reponse)

    return q

def poser(self):
    print("QUESTION")
    print("  " + self.titre)
    for i in range(len(self.choix)):
        print("  ", i+1, "-", self.choix[i])

    print()
    resultat_response_correcte = False
    reponse_int = Question.demander_reponse_numerique_utlisateur(1, len(self.choix))
    if self.choix[reponse_int-1] == self.bonne_reponse:
        print("Bonne réponse")
        resultat_response_correcte = True
    else:
        print("Mauvaise réponse")

    print()
    return resultat_response_correcte
```

Thank a lot.

Comment: We're missing too much of your code to help.  For example, self.bonne_reponse is not assigned in the code you're showing so it may contain anything.  If it is the list of True/False then your condition should be `if self.bonne_reponse[reponse_int-1]:`  By the way, a tomato IS a fruit so your program is actually smarter than you think :).

Comment: @ Alain T.  Thank for you information, if self.bonne_reponse[reponse_int-1]:  work perfectely. And i know tomato is a fruit, this  come from a Json file like this.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using a dictionary to store your choice-bool pairs.

```
choices = {'tomatos':True, 'apple':False, 'grappe':False, 'citrus':False}

q='Which of the following is  not a fruit?\n'
for choice in choices.keys():
    q+=choice+'\n'

choosen=input(q)
if choices[choosen]==True:
    print('correct answer')
else:
    print('wrong answer')
```